# How to add new chapter to an existing project?

Tags: chapters

Im new to the LaTeX. I'm working with the existing project, but now I want to add a new chapter to it. The document class i'm using is `book`. 
Please help me.

Comment: Just use `\chapter[Short text for the table of contents]{Long text for the document}`.

Comment: A minimal working example would help.  If you want to add `filename.tex`, one uses the `\input{filename}`  or  `\include{filename}` commands.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my standard 'minimal' book frame for quick answers to TeX.SX! It can be used as a MWE for quick addition of content.

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\listoffigures
%\listoftables
\part{The First Part}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}
\paragraph{First paragraph}
\subparagraph{First subparagraph}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}
\paragraph{First paragraph}
\subparagraph{First subparagraph}



%\printindex
%\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use LaTeX for writing novels, historical (factual) books and scripts (radio drama). Here is an example main document for a working novel. I would be happy to share with you style files etc if that would be useful. I should point out I have been using LaTeX for a number of years specifically for publishing books and scripts.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,english,british,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
 \usepackage{mystyle}
 \begin{document}
 \title{\mytitle}
    \author{}
    \date{}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
    \begin{titlepage}
            \begin{flushright}
    {\huge \mytitle}
    \par\end{flushright}{\huge \par}
    \end{titlepage}

    \begin{titlepage}
            \noindent\includegraphics[width=4in,height=2in]{../img/titr_ben_sig}
            \vspace*{0.5in}
            \begin{flushright}
    \Huge{Tears in the Rain}
    \par\end{flushright}{\Huge \par}

    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{center}
            \emph{Copyright}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
            \textcopyright{ 2014 Ben Francis All rights reserved.}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{0.5in}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\paperwidth}
        No part of this publication may be reproduced ...
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{0.5in}
    \begin{center}
            ISBN:
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{0.2in}
    \begin{center}
            A CIP Record for this book is available from the British
    Library.
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{0.1in}
    \begin{center}
            Typeset in \LaTeXe
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Preface}
    \input{./titr_ccc_preface.tex}

\mainmatter

\input{matter.tex}

\end{document}
```

This should give you a fair idea of how to set up the book. If you need more help PM me if you need the files.